# Fullcalendar.io - just load events per period of view

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I use Fullcalendar.io v5.9.0 in an angular application and want to achieve that only the events for the view-period are loaded. This works onInit but I have no idea, how I can get the new period after changing the view (i.e. 1 week earlier or later).

Component:

```
export class EventListComponent {

  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: ''
    },
    locale: deLocale,
    initialView: 'listWeek',
    initialEvents: (arg) => { this.initEvents(arg.start, arg.end) }, // here
    weekends: true,
    editable: false,
    selectable: true,
    selectMirror: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true,
    select: this.openAddEventDialog.bind(this),
    eventClick: this.openEditEventDialog.bind(this)
  };

  constructor(
    private readonly eventService: EventService
  ) { }

  // here
  async initEvents(viewStart: Date, viewEnd: Date): Promise<void> {
    /* console.log('viewStart: ', viewStart);
    console.log('viewEnd: ', viewEnd); */
    const allCalendarEvents: EventInput[] = [];
    const allEvents = await this.eventService.getAllEventsOfView(viewStart, viewEnd).toPromise();

    for (const event of allEvents) {
      allCalendarEvents.push({ id: event.id.toString(), title: event.name, start: event.start_timestamp.toString(), end: event.end_timestamp.toString() });
    }

    this.calendarOptions.events = allCalendarEvents;
  }
}
```

Thx

Comment: I found the solution: "initialEvents: (arg) => { this.initEvents(arg.start, arg.end) }" has to be changed to "datesSet: (arg) => { this.initEvents(arg.start, arg.end) }"

Comment: Or use one of the patterns advised in the documentation for this purpose - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function